# Mod candidates can be dragged under the "Clear all" button when voting in an election

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, election

If all moderator candidates are added to the voting list, then when moving their order around, you're able to place them under the "Clear All" button in the list.

Pics below from Board & Card Games Stack Exchange 2021 moderator election:

[image: candidates for election, with one below "Clear all"]
[image: candidates for election, with four below "Clear all"]
[image: candidates for election, with all below "Clear all"]

Comment: Don't forget these bugs sometime clear the choices: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371251/bug-with-election-drag-next-selection-here-gets-treated-as-a-candidate#comment1239123_371251

Comment: Added to our devs' backlog to be addressed as part of bug duty rotation. We'll update this post once we have anything new to report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed. The position of the [Clear all] button is no longer able to be manipulated in the sortable list of candidates.

> Oh [Clear all] label
> Voters moved you up and down
> Now is fixed in place!