# "(drag next selection here)" is treated as a candidate in an election

Tags: bug, status-planned, election

I have recently came across a very strange bug.

"(drag next selection here)" gets treated as a candidate.

I attached a GIF image to reproduce it exactly:

https://i.imgur.com/xXgiiNT.mp4

As you can see in the GIF image, the "(drag next selection here)" can be moved.

What happens is:

1. Put every candidate into the ballot area.
2. The "(All candidates have been selected)" message comes up.
3. It can be moved to the ballot area.
4. After it is moved into the ballot area, it becomes drag "next selection here"

Also, if you didn't realize, the rankings get messed up since "(drag next selection here)" becomes an element in the table.

The rankings become:

[image]

I dragged "(drag next selection here)" into the third candidate position, and it gets messed up.

It becomes:

```
1.

2.

4.

...
```

Also, after I do this, at the end, when I click "clear all", it becomes:

[image]

Which is strange...

It removes everything, which obviously doesn't happen when I don't drag the "(drag next selection here)" text.

**To sum it up: There are a lot of bugs with this...**

It was repro'ed on Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81.

Comment: No repro for me, on Chrome/Win10. Please specify what browser you're using and OS. Also, try to disable all userscripts, including adblockers, and see if it still happens. If not, we know it's not SE fault but something on your end.

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 95.0a1 and Chrome 95.0.4638.54. Related: [Able to drag mod candidates under clear all when voting](/q/371242/289905).

Comment: reproduced: 95.0.4638.54/ windows 7. shit. Now I have messed up my ballot of the Tex.SE moderator election.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 Hey, Look this gif by him, you have to drag *them all* and **then** the *all candidate...* thing. https://i.imgur.com/xXgiiNT.mp4

Comment: But the inspect tools shows nothing is send in the field of `CandidateToVoteIndex:` it is just `{}`, And a refresh clears it all so my ballot is all right...

Comment: Time to change my alias to "(drag next selection here)" - maybe I'll win the next mod election!

Comment: @JonCuster No, there'll be a pot full of names for the next selection.